# Destination net unreachable

Tags: linux

Here is my problem. I've got a router and a client machine (call it C1) but I can't ping internet on C1. The result is :

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.4.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.4.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.4.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Unreachable
....
```

My router is configured as :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.203.134
netmask 255.255.255.0 

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.4.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

My client is configured as :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.4.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.4.3
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I did the command

```
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And here I am lost because all seems ok for me...

If you need anything else, ask me and thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first check inter net in router.  Ping from your router

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

If it is ok. Then edit the iptables  rules P replace to A

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```